# Smart Object Not Transforming Correctly In Animation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, smartobject

I'm doing a simple animation mockup and for some reason, a section of the smart object layer won't stay. The animation is simple. The iPhone just moved right then back left again. The bottom corner seems to always reset its position. No matter how many times I change the position once I move the timeline the size resets again. Any suggestions? I've been trying to google suggestions for 2 days straight and found nothing so far. I recorded my screen so you can see what I'm exactly doing. and I also provided the original file below just in case you would like to test it out yourself.

---

**Note**

one thing I did try was changing to hold interpolation and going frame by frame and still doesn't work.

Tried going to the frame animation area and doing it that way. still no change.

Tried adding more keyframes to smoothen it out. still not working.

---

**Screen recording I made just to show the problem quickly** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy1iQWrPWrM

**Original file if you'd like to see yourself.**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YNedpgcDT8ajRRV0l0UFRuTkU/view?usp=sharing